# Does Tree package in R provide class label as the result of prediction?

Tags: r

I'm a newbie in R, and have a question regarding "Tree" package.
I'm have created a classification model with the package, and now I want to try prediction. But I have no idea on how to do the prediction as well as class labeling. 
All I've done so far is create the model with my training set and test set, and figure out its accuracy. But is there a way to do the actual prediction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many models in R, you can use the `predict` function on new data points in order to get predictions for them, as well as class labels. More specifically, for a `tree` object, there is a specific [doc](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tree/versions/1.0-40/topics/predict.tree) page for its optional arguments.

In general, to get predictions on new data you can use this command

```
predict(your_tree_model, new_data)
```

and to get class labels

```
predict(your_tree_model, new_data, type = "class")
```